# How to test AngularJs with protractor, contenteditable with 'bold' modifier, broken since webdriver update

Tags: angularjs, protractor, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, contenteditable

Consider this AngularJs app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
AngularJs insert text after bold checked
</title>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('ngTestBoldInsert', []);
    app.controller('ngCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.boldButtonClicked = function () {            
            document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
        };
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="ngTestBoldInsert" ng-controller="ngCtrl">
<h2>Edit text after click on checkbox</h2>
<label for="boldButtonId">Bold</label>
<input id="boldButtonId" type="checkbox" ng-change="boldButtonClicked()" ng-model="boldStatus">
<br /><br />
    <div id="textFrame" contenteditable="true" style="padding:10px; border:1px solid black; width:30%; ">text</div>
</div>
    <p>Manual: click on edit frame, input text, Click on 'bold' checkbox. click on edit frame, input some text. Now the text is bold. <br /><br />Please note that this is a simplification, in real application the bold button status is synced with the status of the text but that would make this example very complicated.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this protractor test:

```
'use strict';


describe('text editor', function() {


    var textFrame = element(by.id('textFrame'));    
    var boldCheckbox = element(by.id('boldButtonId'));


    it('should insert normal text', function() {
        browser.get('index.html#!/');
        var text = textFrame.getText();
        expect(text).toBe('text');
        textFrame.click();
        textFrame.sendKeys(' plus normal text');
        text = textFrame.getText();
        expect(text).toBe('text plus normal text');

        var html = browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", textFrame);
        expect(html).toBe('text plus normal text');
    });

    it('should insert bold text', function() {
        boldCheckbox.click();
        textFrame.click();
        textFrame.sendKeys('plus bold text');

        var text = textFrame.getText();
        expect(text).toBe('text plus normal textplus bold text');

        var html = browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", textFrame);
        expect(html).toBe('text plus normal text<b>plus bold text</b>');
    });

});
```

This test works until chromedriver_76.0.3809.68

and is broken in chromedriver_77.0.3865.40

caused by webdriver update: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2704

Text is no longer bold in the test.

output of the test:

```
Expected 'text plus normal textplus bold text' to be 'text plus normal text<b>plus bold text</b>'.
```

How to test this now?

Comment: What is the output of 'html'? What does the errors says?

Comment: output of html is 'text plus normal textplus bold text', expected fails with Expected 'text plus normal textplus bold text' to be 'text plus normal text<b>plus bold text</b>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use actions as mentioned by the w3c/webdriver team
https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/1469

actions api: https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#actions

instead of textFrame.click() and textFrame.sendKeys
use
code:

```
browser.actions().click(textFrame).sendKeys('text plus normal textplus bold text').perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try `element.getAttribute("innerHTML")`

If doesn't help, do `element.getAttribute("outterHTML")` it will return you a string like `<div id="textFrame" contenteditable="true" style="padding:10px; border:1px solid black; width:30%; ">text plus normal text<b>plus bold text</b></div>`, so then just do `expect(html).toContain('text plus normal text<b>plus bold text</b>');`

In worst case scenario, if you don't want to go this route, you have no options but to report a bug with chromedriver team, which I would suggest to do anyway, since its community driven effort